# Running mongo command from bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am trying to run the following command from bash script

```
db['STUDENT_DOCUMENTS.chunks'].find({
    _id: {
        $in: [
            ObjectId("57ce3bc6e4b0ee0234924cb4"),
            ObjectId("57a40750e4b03808d591b5cb"),
            ObjectId("57b17588e4b03808d594ceec"),
            ObjectId("57b2e03ee4b03808d595246f"),
            ObjectId("57c786bde4b03808d598eb41")
        ]
    }
})
```

Where the `ObjectId` is on a separated file totaling more than 100+ and I need
to login to mongodb with username and password and output the result in a file
how this can be done in bash shell script?

I was thinking of some thing like this

```
for i in 'cat ObjectId.txt" ; do \
mongo 127.0.0.1:10000/admin --username=user --password=pass \
--eval "db['Student_DOCUMENTS.chunks'].find({_id :{$in: [ObjectId("$i")
]}})
```

when running this script redirect the output to a file
Is this doable with bash script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have all your ids in a file called `id.txt` delimited by new line :

- build the id list to be included in the `$in` in your find request (`ObjectId('...'),...`)
- Use `--quiet` in order not to include mongodb connection log
- Redirect the output with `> your_file.json`

Bash script :

```
file=id.txt
id_list=

while IFS= read -r id || [[ -n "$id" ]];
do
    if [ ! -z "$id_list" ]; then
        id_list="$id_list, ObjectId(\"$id\")"
    else
        id_list="ObjectId(\"$id\")"
    fi
done <"$file"

request="db['Student_DOCUMENTS.chunks'].find({_id :{\$in: ["$id_list"]}})"

mongo 127.0.0.1:10000/admin --username=user --password=pass \
    --quiet --eval "$request" > request.json
```